# UITableViewCell from IB Shows Value as NULL

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitableview

The following is being used as the code to put a tableviewcell from a nib file into the tableview. I have taken the tableviewcell in the same nib as that of the tableview. I have tried initializing the cell in the viewdidload also but to no go.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"identifier";
    NSLog(@"the cellidentifier is %@", CellIdentifier);
    bookmarksTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"the cell is %@", bookmarksTableViewCell);
    return bookmarksTableViewCell;
}
```

The error that I get is

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I have checked connections in the IB and rewired them too but the result comes up the same. When I try NSLog'ing the cell, it comes as null.

Comment: Did you set the identifier of the cell in Interface Builder to "indentifier"?  I would call it something else like "Custom Cell" or "Bookmark Cell" or something that identifies what it is.  Here you are calling for a cell with identifier "identifier".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like so

```
static NSString *CellIdenetifier = @"Cell";

BookMarksTableViewCell *cell = (BookMarksTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
   cell = [[BookMarksTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubTitle reuseIdentifer:CellIdentifier]; 
}
```

Im not sure if you need that if but I thought I include it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solves the crashing problem but the graphical elements (like a static UILabel) that I put in this UITableViewCell in the XIB file doesn't show up. Instead, I get blank cells. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you do something like this `cell.labelName.text = @"text"` thats how you would set the text of a label. make sure that it is properly connected in the nib. Also make sure you use the `@property` in h and `synthesize` in m for that Label

Comment: I am not even doing that. I just put a label with some text over there  (in the IB itself) and it doesn't even show that. The background has been applied through IB and still doesn't show in the actual table.

Comment: Can you post that code please. It seems like something is either not connected or not right in your code. Is your label inside the table and the table isn't showing up? Or is the label separate from the table and is not showing up?

Comment: I did the code with completely different approach now and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"identifier";
    NSLog(@"the cellidentifier is %@", CellIdentifier);

    bookmarksTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (bookmarksTableViewCell == nil){
            //allocate your cell here
    }

    return bookmarksTableViewCell;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solves the crashing problem but the graphical elements (like a static UILabel) that I put in this UITableViewCell in the XIB file doesn't show up. Instead, I get blank cells. Any suggestions?

Comment: set a unique tag (9876 or something random but unique) to that uilabel in IB. in your cellForRow do UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[bookmarksTableViewCell viewWithTag:9876]. and then do whatever you want to do with theLabel

Comment: I did the code with completely different approach now and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: sharing how you fixed it will help others looking for the same solution!

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is null.

If a table view needs to display more cells than available in its queue, it returns nil from

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
```

to ask the data source for creating a new cell until the sufficient amount of cells are allocated. Check for NULL:

```
bookmarksTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (bookmarksTableViewCell == NULL)
    bookmarksTableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStylePlain reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

return cell;
```

Ah, ps.: forget about Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error is now gone but the cells that shows up in the tableview doesn't have any of the labels, background color or any other graphical property that I had put in the tableviewcell.

Comment: You need to set them manually. It's far beyond the scope of IB to manage this. If you wanna program, at some point you'll eventually need to type code by hand. I guess this time has come for you.

Comment: ^ Thanks for your reply. I usually do all the cellForRowAtIndexPath coding by hand but this one time I thought to try IB's UITableViewCell object as it can be handy considering that I will have a lot of graphical elements in this tableviewcell and managing them all can be very, very cumbersome. Can I ask why do you think it's out of scope of IB considering that IB has the UiTableViewCell object in place? Thank you.

Comment: @Shukaku IB only makes life hard when one moves from simple static views to even from a basic table view. Such a tool, I think, should not be available for programmers but for designers. Unfortunately, it's not as useful is it might be expected. (Nevertheless, I'm developing iOS apps on Linux; as such, there's no IB for me and I'm fully happy with my command-line-only toolchain...)

Comment: @H2CO3.  I have to disagree with you about interface builder and `UITableViewCell`s.  You can create a custom cell class, and build the UI completely in interface builder and link up the IBOutlets all very quickly and easily.  It is much faster and easier than coding the positions and properties of all of the elements.

Comment: I did the code with completely different approach now and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for your help.